# Is it allowed(good karma) to marry many wives as practiced by Hindu gods?

Tags: krishna, gods, dharma, marriage

I have heard that Krishna had more than 16000 wives and many children. So my question is, is it right to practice polygamy? How moral is it?

We know that Kunti had five sons. It is written in scriptures that she got five boons whereby she can call upon any god and be blessed with a baby. Thinking scientifically, this must have involved sex (more likely) or a form of modern technology like artificial insemination.

I am not entirely convinced the Hinduism we follow now is very different from its earlier form. Polygamy is considered to be a sin/crime in today's world, or at least most Hindus oppose it.

The concept of god itself is so mystical and complex. I believe, no humans can be considered god, but maybe messengers or demigod.

Comment: Nobody considers polygamy a sin. Other religions also have polygamy. It's considered a crime only because laws forbid it.

Comment: as practiced by Hindu gods --- actually most Hindu gods (I don't know if all is the correct word) have one consort only.. For eg- Shiva-Parvati, Vishnu-Laxmi, Brahma-Saraswati, Indra-Sachi... But Hindu scriptures allow humans to marry more than once..

Comment: @Rickross Vishnu has 3 wives. Lakshmi, Bhu, and Nila. Purusha suktam says "hrishca te lakshmischa patnyou," which means "Hri (Bhu) and Sri (Lakshmi) are your wives."

Comment: @Rickross Shiva has more than 1 wife.

Comment: Who are the wives? I knw abt Gauri only  @Wikash_hindu

Comment: The mantra that you are talking about has Sun has it's deity and not Vishnu. PurushaSukta's deity is also not Vishnu. Yeah I also know that .. even Ganga, Saraswati and Tulasi are also regarded as his wives.. but usually we associate mostly/only Laxmi with him.. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Hinduism say about polygamy (multiple marriages)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/557/what-does-hinduism-say-about-polygamy-multiple-marriages)

Comment: Although not shown above, I voted to close this one as dup of [What does Hinduism say about polygamy (multiple marriages)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/557/what-does-hinduism-say-about-polygamy-multiple-marriages)

Comment: @Rickross Who do you think Purusha Suktam's deity is? I don't know any, even Vaishnavas, who associate Saraswati, Ganga, etc as wives of Vishnu.

Comment: Why is this question flagged as opinion based? The Hindu scriptures talk about marrying multiple wives!

Comment: You should edit your question. Moral or not is subjective. But Hindu scriptures accept Polygamy in certain cases.

Comment: there was no sex involved in begetting the children by devatas. refer to original mahabharata text ('yonir yatha na dushyetha') before forming half-baked opinions.